# What is the Dependency property in WPF

Tags: binding

What is the Dependency property in WPF and Silverlight.

Why we required and where we can use it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx):

> The purpose of dependency properties
>   is to provide a way to compute the
>   value of a property based on the value
>   of other inputs. These other inputs
>   might include system properties such
>   as themes and user preference,
>   just-in-time property determination
>   mechanisms such as data binding and
>   animations/storyboards, multiple-use
>   templates such as resources and
>   styles, or values known through
>   parent-child relationships with other
>   elements in the element tree.

So they're like normal properties, but their value can be automatically computed from the values of other properties.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on dependency properties here:

http://www.betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2010/01/24/wpf-silverlight-xaml-and-dependency-properties.aspx